# Will photorec copy/restore existing files too? Is that possible to avoid that?

Tags: data-recovery, file-recovery, photorec

My Environment: `Linux (debian)`

App in Question: `photorec`

Hi, It seems `photorec` will copy/restore my existing files too. Is this what photorec does? Is that possible to tell photorec **NOT** to copy my existing files? I just want it to recover all deleted/missing files. When it copies everything, it's really hard for me to tell what are missing and what are not missing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Photorec reads the raw disk (it has no concept of a filesystem) and dumps any data with signatures it recognises to disk. It has no way of knowing what the filesystem knows or sees as deleted.

If you still have a valid filesystem it is probably not the appropriate tool to use to undelete files - but without knowing what filesystem you are working on or how old the deleted data is we can't advise you!